# Embed a Google Calendar including External ICAL web calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to embed a Google calendar IFrame that should include an aggregate of multiple normal Google calendars including one external iCal format calendar.

The iCal file is generated by a PHP script that retrieves records from a SQL database and makes them into iCal format.

However, when embedding the Google Calendar IFrame on the site, I get this message:

[image: Events from one or more calendars could not be shown here because you do not have the permission to view them.]

> Events from one or more calendars could not be shown here because you do not have the permission to view them.

So I tried to *share* the calendar, to make it public, but in the Google Calendar GUI I cannot: the drop-down for the external calendar doesn't have a `Share this calendar` option (the normal calendars do, though).

Questions:

1) How do I make the external calendar public/shareable?

2) Any other alternative to programmatically display events in a Google Calendar?

Comment: If it's an external calendar, then it's already public right.?

Comment: One should think so! But we're "routing it through" Google Calendar to get to get a visual calendar of the Ical feed.

Comment: Since they're all public urls - how about posting them and we could give it a try in our google calendars?